# How to get ling prediction (something like GNN algorithm) in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

On the [MAGE algorithm page](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/algorithms/machine-learning-graph-analytics/gnn-algorithm) I've found the Graph Neural Network algorithm, but it says that it has not been implemented yet.

Is there a way to get link prediction in Memgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link prediction can be achieved using [node2vec from MAGE](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/algorithms/machine-learning-graph-analytics/node2vec-algorithm).

For this to work, you will need:

- The [MAGE graph library](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/installation)
- [Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/lab) - the graph explorer for querying Memgraph and visualizing graphs
- [gqlalchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy) - a Python driver and object graph mapper (OGM)

The complete procedure is described in the article [Link prediction with Node2Vec in Physics Collaboration Network](https://memgraph.com/blog/link-prediction-with-node2vec-in-physics-collaboration-network).